# All cygwin git repos becoming corrupt on reboot

Tags: git, cygwin

So I have a gitolite setup currently running in cygwin and everything works fine during the initial gl-setup; I can push/pull from the repositories all day long with no problem.  However, the second I reboot my machine, every single repository becomes corrupt.  I took pre/post reboot tars and, using kdiff, see that all of the files under the "objects" directory have changed... significantly.  The files in my local copy (still on windows but not in cygwin) do not change however.

To give you an example of how extreme the changes are... here are the hex dumps of a random object:

Pre:

```
78 01 2B 29 4A 4D 55 30 33 61 30 31 00 02 85 E4  x.+)JMU03a01..…ä
FC BC 34 86 90 9D 41 31 26 67 84 8E BB 38 BD 5D  ü¼4†..A1&g„Ž»8½]
BC 48 30 55 EB C5 A2 EB B6 10 E9 EC D4 CA 94 CC  ¼H0UëÅ¢ë¶.éìÔÊ”Ì
22 86 AD DF DE D6 27 44 FC 7C FA 6D DA 89 15 7B  "†­ßÞÖ'Dü|úmÚ‰.{
37 4D EC 11 54 B9 F2 14 00 C6 66 1F 3E           7Mì.T¹ò..Æf.>
```

Post:

```
39 D5 AD B9 06 05 A0 7D 8F D2 16 F9 34 DA 62 EE  9Õ­¹.. }.Ò.ù4Úbî
21 2C D3 17 7D 35 11 4C 5E 88 58 C2 DA 09 FA C3  !,Ó.}5.L^ˆXÂÚ.úÃ
25 48 C9 07 29 A3 E3 E5 F6 7F 91 C4 29 D9 45 A3  %HÉ.)£ãåö.‘Ä)ÙE£
20 A6 07 DB 94 77 F4 7C 6D 59 E5 CC C0 08 35 91   ¦.Û”wô|mYåÌÀ.5‘
FF 22 6A 3E F5 0A 44 94 18 39 8E D0 6B           ÿ"j>õ.D”.9ŽÐk
```

I came across a [post from git-users](http://www.mail-archive.com/git-users@googlegroups.com/msg00363.html) where somebody else had the same problem and it turns out that I'm using full-disk encryption as well (PGP Desktop) so I wonder if that's the root cause.

If anybody has any ideas, I'd be incredibly grateful!

Answer (score 0):

First, it is not clear in your question if you are using yourself a full disk encryption.

Then, an anti-virus might have some unintended side-effect: deactivating it just for one reboot might be interesting to check if the problem persists.

Finally, it could be about a mount issue, as [illustrated by this thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/cygwin@cygwin.com/msg03878.html%29):

> The problem was that the working directory from which imports and adds where done resided on a text mount. After mounting it in binary mode and starting a fresh repository,
>   everything is fine.